# Semi-responsive build chopped off viewed on iPad

Tags: ipad, responsive-design

I have not a link to share at this point but was wondering if anyone had come across the same problem as myself.

I have made a responsive website, the client requested that the site should be responsive from 1080px in width down to 960px in width, this was easy to build and works on the Desktop but on the ipad in portrait the website is chopped off, in landscape however its perfect.

I'm thinking its something to do with the initial width being used on render..

I've tried:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width; initial-scale = 1; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable = no;" />
```

and

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.7">
```

as a "fix" maybe I should set a fixed width for ipad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave your meta with initial-scale = 1;

Then go in you media queries and find if you are checking for ipad dimensions

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
```

Please bare in mind that you need extra media queries for ipad3/4